# aws cognito SAML federation authentication in java

Tags: java, saml-2.0, amazon-cognito

I have configured Cognito user pool and has also setup SAML user pool federation. The app client is configured to use SAML identity and Cognito User Pool as Enabled Identity Providers.

Now, How should i use java api to tell cognito which user should use which identity provider?

If user A is using xxxx.com domain he should use Cognito User Pool identity and if user B is using yyyy.com domain, then he should be directed to use SAML identity,

How can i pass the identifer information through java api to cognito authentication? If so please let me know with an example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> How can i pass the identifer information through java api to cognito authentication?

I don't think you can decide the identity provider upfront before the user is authenticated. When user is not authenticated yet, you simply don't know which IdP to use. AWS Cognito will allow all enabled

If I am mistaken, feel free to correct me

> How should i use java api to tell cognito which user should use which identity provider?

I'd suggest to try the pre-authentication lambda trigger allowing to validate the authentication information, e.g. you could validate if user from certain domain used the correct IdP

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-authentication.html

I never did it myself so - I have no idea what the actial response will contain, you can try it out yourself

Comment: Thanks for the answer @gusto2. I got an example to authenticate using AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoAuth in javascript, but the /oauth2/authorize endpoint only supports HTTPS GET and the user pool client makes this request through a browser which was given in the aws doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authorization-endpoint.html                                                                                                                        
My question here is, Is there a way to achieve this using java and is there any api methods to handle this?